# Stop Horizontal Scroll - All pages

Tags: html, css, mobile, scroll

In mobile view, I have a navigational link that has negative margins. It displays when touching a button.
My issue is this is causing my mobile view to horizontally scroll.

Is there a way I can keep the navigational bar with negative margins and stop horizontal scrolling?

This is the first time I've built a website

```
@media(max-width: 800px){
  html{
  overflow-x:auto !important;
  }
  body{
  overflow-x:auto !important;
  }
```

The above has no effect.

Comment: What do you _need_ those negative margins for? Might make more sense to try and eliminate those, than to mess with the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of using**

```
@media(max-width: 800px){
  html{
  overflow-x:auto !important;
  }
  body{
  overflow-x:auto !important;
  }
```

Just use **overflow:hidden**

```
@media(max-width: 800px){
body{
  overflow:hidden;
   }
 }
```

this should work .

Comment: This would make the site unable to scroll vertically. `overflow-x: hidden` might work, though.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my question that I have already used the code you have suggested without any luck.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Leave the `overflow` on the `body` alone; just keep the default styles from the browser.

Since the nav's parent element is already `100vh` tall, the easiest solution is to simply control the overflow on that element. I have put together a simplified version of your code below as a demo.

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks")

function showMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "0";
}

function hideMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
}
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden; /* add this */
}

.nav-links {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 1s;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: white;
}

section:not(:first-child) {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: gold;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <section class="header">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
        <!-- use a real button; put your icon inside it -->
        <button onclick="hideMenu()" type="button">close</button>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/page-1">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/page-2">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="/page-3">Page 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="/page-4">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- use a real button; put your icon inside it -->
    <button onclick="showMenu()" type="button">open</button>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras auctor neque velit, non tempus lacus molestie non. Vivamus urna tortor, posuere et nibh et, euismod porta leo.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras auctor neque velit, non tempus lacus molestie non. Vivamus urna tortor, posuere et nibh et, euismod porta leo.</p>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

One thing to note: in the event that someone is using a keyboard to navigate your site on these smaller screen sizes, you're going to run into trouble with this nav design. As soon as someone hits the tab key, the browser is going to yoink the off-screen link into the viewport, which will totally mess up your JS logic. The solution to that problem is:

1. Use actual `<button>` elements around your open/close icons, so they can be reached via the tab key.
2. Give all the links within the nav `tabindex="-1"` while they are hidden, so the only thing a keyboard user can get to initially is the button to open the menu. When you click the open button, remove the `tabindex` attribute from the links, or update it to `tabindex="0"`. Then put it back to `tabindex="-1"` when you close the menu.

Comment: Thank you,
I added the following:

      overflow: hidden; /* add this */

Still no change to the side scroll unfortunately. Was there something I've missed?

I will change the buttons as you have advised, thanks again

Comment: @ZoePesarra when I pull up your site in Chrome's device emulation mode, that one style fixes the problem. Maybe the code you're working on has changed some other things that affected the solution compared to what's live? You should update your question with a snippet of code that reproduces the problem. See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information.